# updatepanel refresh the whole page when put it in an html table

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, updatepanel

this is how I organize the page:

```
<table>
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ctlUpdatePanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
     <td>
     </td>
     <td>
          //asp:button
     </td>
             </ContentTemplate>               
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
     <td>
            //some items
     </td>
</table>
```

I don't want to refresh the third `td` when I click the `asp:button` in the second `td`.

But click refreshes the whole page.  It seems the updatepanel doesn't work?why>

Comment: `asp:UpdatePanel` translates to a `div` - you can't nest a `div` between `table` and `td` - move the panel inside the `td` `<td><asp:UpdatePanel>...</asp:UpdatePanel></td>`   To update a panel from outside, there's a 'target' property of some kind (it's been too many years since I've used archaic asp.net, so not a full answer).

Comment: The first `td` and the second `td` should refresh each other when the button in it is clicked. But buttons in the first `td` is generated dynamically when the page loads. So how could I set triggers of the updatepanel in the second `td`

Comment: Quick SO search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876779/trigger-a-asp-net-event-from-a-control-placed-outside-the-update-panel Add an `<asp:ASyncPostBackTrigger` and then trigger it from your dynamic button (probably using a hidden button inside the content as your trigger).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by freedomn-m, you cannot put the UpdatePanel in that position, since it would be equivalent to this invalid HTML:

```
<table>
     <div>
         <td>
         </td>
         <td>
             //asp:button
         </td>
     </div>
     <td>
         //some items
     </td>
</table>
```

You can insert the UpdatePanel in a cell of your table and put its content in an inner table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ctlUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                // other content
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                // asp:button
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </td>
        <td>
            // other items
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the inner table will not have the same columns as the outer table.  In the example here, there's only one row, but in OPs code there's no row, so could be *guessed* that there's more than one row and this will have different columns on every row.  Unless you fix the column widths ofc.

Comment: I agree. I did not go into details here but I could suggest to set `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` to zero for all tables (inner and outer) and to apply a class style to the outer table and another one to the inner table to fix the column widths.